# How do I set the "Switch tabs" hotkey?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, 16.10, 17.04

I haven't been able to find it in Settings > Keyboard, nor other places.

I just switched to GNOME, and realized I still have the same trouble. Why is this not listed as a shortcut, along with Switch Windows within an app, Switch Apps, etc?

By default, this is ctrl+tab. I want to change it.

Comment: if you want to cycle through all your windows press Alt+Tab repeatedly, but i somehow think you're not talking about that

Comment: Im talking about switching tabs.

Comment: @TomMercer Tabs of *what*? Lots of things have tabs.

Comment: For example, firefox and chrome, but also I would like every application.

In windows and mac, this is easily accomplished. I can't imagine the code for "switch tab" is different for different apps. It's an OS-level shortcut.

Comment: @TomMercer No, it's not an OS-level shortcut. It is specific to each app. For example, in gnome-terminal the shortcut is Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn. Not Ctrl+Tab.

Comment: So, I should hunt for ways to change "Switch tabs" shortcut in each browser?

I'm aware that terminal ignores switch tabs shortcut, as well as all kinds of other OS-level shortcuts. For example, control and alt are different in Terminal, middle-click is different, can't use shortcuts to copy/paste/quit/hide in terminal like you can in every other app/window.

Comment: Also, I noticed your profile says you hate systemd. I can't PM on this forum, but want to ask if could you explain why? I've read a couple articles on how the debate over systemd fractured entire Linux communities. I have no real "skin in the game". Just think it's interesting how intense the conflict is.

Comment: I came from Mac, where Terminal also had different keyboard shorcut behavior. On OSX it was because Terminal was running on a lower-level window manager, windowing system, or desktop environment. I guess I assume it's the same in Linux. Do you know?

You know how ctrl+c or ctrl+q or ctrl+w in Terminal aren't like the whole rest of the OS? Is that why?